# Pattern matching a map within a map in the function header

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I currently have a params instance that looks like this:

```
  params: %{
    "continent" => %{
      "deleted_date" => nil,
      "name" => "Asia",
      "to_be_deleted" => true
    },
    "id" => "16"
  },
```

I am trying to pattern match against the `to_be_deleted` key so that if it is true, a different version of `update/2` will run, whilst also assigning the content of `continents` to `continent_params`

My current `update/2`:

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "continent" => continent_params}) do
    # stuff         
  end
```

My attempt to pattern match a different version:

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, %{"to_be_deleted" = true} => continent_params}) do
    #stuff
  end
```

However this produces a syntax warning regarding a `}` that I can't clear. I'm unsure whether I am trying to do too much in the function header or whether I should be using a different syntax to access the 'map within the map'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "continent" => %{"to_be_deleted" = true} = continent_params}) do
  #stuff                       ^
end
```

You forgot to pattern match against `"continent"` Key.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I also had to correct my own typo for `%{"to_be_deleted" => true}`. I didn't match against `"continent"` because in my head I was thinking "Do not try and use continent.to_be_deleted, you are not writing JS"!